# Python: Find all integers inside string and store in list as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, list-comprehension

Looking for an efficient way to search for all integers in a string and append them to a list. E.g. '(12, 15)' should become [12, 15]. Integers that are greater than 9, should remain joined and not separated when appended to the list.

If there is a way to use built-in functions, lambda or list comprehension, could you share those specifically? Thanks.

What I have so far seems too bloated.

```
user_input = '(3, 10)' # or '3 10'

def sti(n):
    s = ''
    l = []
    for index, item in enumerate(n):
        if item.isdigit():
            s += item
        if not item.isdigit():
            l.append(s)
            s = ''

    l.append(s)
    a = list(filter(None, l)) # remove spaces
    a = list(map(lambda x: int(x), a)) # convert to int
    return a

print(sti(user_input))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re

print(list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', user_input))))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't know how to use regex with map and didn't consider importing re. This is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

If

```
new_string = "lol69on420for666"
```

then you can do something like,

```
for letter in new_string:
    if letter == "0" or \
       letter == "1" or \
             ...
       letter == "9":
            append the letter to some list
```

or

```
if "6" in new_string:
    append "6" to some list
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no negative numbers, you could use `itertools.groupby` together with `str.isdecimal`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> list(map(int, map(''.join, map(itemgetter(1), filter(itemgetter(0), groupby('(3, 10)', str.isdecimal))))))
[3, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much better without importing any package. `v` is the string

```
new_list = [int(item) for item in v if item.isdigit()]
```

Comment: i like that it's a list comprehension, although this separates the integers. So '3 13' would become [3,1,3] when i need it to do [3, 13]. Do you know a way to do this in a list compression and without any modules?